# what are the things should be done when start work on a new module in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, alm

My ASP.NET project was integrated with Microsoft **VSTS**. what are the steps should follow to deliver a new module in proper time manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, the most suitable answer is "it depends" ...

In test-driven development, for example, you start with writing your tests and then develop against these tests.

What I do and did in projects is getting an idea at first. I sketch it down on paper / tab s3 and try to create a visual course of what I´m trying to develop.

If I´m satisfied with my sketches, I start building the most simple architecture to achieve my goals, although I always stick to a 3-layer-architecture with dependency injection.

But I always follow my principle "keep IT simple", which means writing short, lean code.

So in short, my procedure in starting a new project is:

1. Write down what you want to achieve
2. Sketches
3. Architecture like DAL, Logic, Web
4. Readable, lean code and tests: "keep IT simple"

I don´t know what else to say to your question. Maybe you could describe your problems more precisely?

Comment: You´re welcome. Besides, creating sketches means sketches for EVERYTHING ;) I even create the database layout using my tab s3 pen.